# What exactly does this snippet do in scala?

Tags: scala, programming-languages

I'm trying to understand the twitter gizzard example rowz, and I can't figure out what this little snippet does in scala:

```
package com.twitter.rowz
import com.twitter.gizzard.nameserver.{Forwarding, NameServer}
import com.twitter.gizzard.shards.ShardException

class ForwardingManager(nameServer: NameServer[Shard]) extends (Long => Shard) {  
    def apply(id: Long) = nameServer.findCurrentForwarding(0, id)
}
```

what exactly is the class extending?

Comment: Seems that you forgot to add new line between `import com.twitter.gizzard.shards.ShardException` and `lass ForwardingManager(name...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(A=>B)` is `Function1[A,B]`

Those lines are strictly equivalent:

```
class ForwardingManager(nameServer: NameServer[Shard]) extends (Long => Shard)
class ForwardingManager(nameServer: NameServer[Shard]) extends Function1[Long,Shard]
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet defines class `ForwardingManager` that extends `Function1[Long, Shard]` (`Long => Shard` is just short form).

As another example, you can look at `Parser` class from Scala library:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala#L190

In ths case `(Input => ParseResult[T])` is the same as `Function1[Input, ParseResult[T]]`. This concrete example is described also in [Programming in Scala, 2nd Edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed) (section 33.6)